# how to set linux hostname based on flashdisk volume label

Tags: bash, scripting, hostname, usb-flash-drive, parsing

i'am running live linux, which run from FAT32 flashdisk
since i run a lot of pc using this flashdisk, its difficult to identify which IP for its hostname, since its ip need to be dynamically determined by dhcp, so i want set their hostname by volume label that is set on its flasdisk

i can use `blkid | grep sda1` or `blkid | grep "vfat"`

the results is

```
#blkid | grep sda1
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SLAX" UUID="FAEB-513E" TYPE="vfat"

#blkid | grep "vfat"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SLAX" UUID="FAEB-513E" TYPE="vfat"
```

but how to parse its label and set to my hostname on boot?

Comment: this is not off topic, i need this to administrate a lot of live usb linux rig, do people even know crypto mining farm running on a lot of disk-less linux machine to do computation using hundreds of GPUs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hostname $(blkid | perl -lne '/LABEL="(.*?)".*vfat/ and print $1')
```

or

```
hostname $(blkid | perl -lne '/sda1.*LABEL="(.*?)"/ and print $1')
```

Since you don't have Perl, your `grep` may not have `-P`. if it does, try

```
hostname $(blkid | grep -Po 'LABEL="\K.*?(?=".*vfat)')
```

or

```
hostname $(blkid | grep -Po 'sda1: LABEL="\K.*?(?=".*)')
```

For a pure Bash version:

```
pattern='sda1.*LABEL="([^"]+)"'    # or: pattern='LABEL="([^"]+)".*vfat'
[[ $(sudo blkid) =~ $pattern ]]
hostname "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: dont have perl on my system, bash script would really help, but thanks for the answering, will accept it

Comment: @uray: see my edits